# Delay Prometheus alert before changing from active to inactive

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have an alert in my Prometheus set up that sends an alert when `someMetric > 100` has been valid for `5m` and then resends the alert every `24h` according to the configuration below:

**prometheus-alert.yml**

```
 - alert: TestAlert
          expr: someMetric > 100
          for: 5m
```

**alertmanager-config.yml**

```
repeat_interval: 24h
```

However `someMetric` has a behaviour where it can be "stable" above 100 (which means an alert is active) but every once in a while it drops to something below 100 for a single scraping before jumping back up above 100. This will cause an *active* alert to become *inactive (resolved)* then back to *pending* and *active* again after 5 min. This will cause Prometheus to resend the alert which is what I want to avoid.

Is there a way to configure Prometheus to have something similar to `for: 5m`, but for the transiction *active* -> *inactive (resolved)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the [aggregation-over-time](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) promQL functions to 'filter out' the blips that dip below 100, in your example? In your case it sounds like max might work? The only down-side being that it could take a few minutes longer to end the alert once the value drops permanently below 100.

```
- alert: TestAlert
      expr: max_over_time(someMetric[2m]) > 100
      for: 5m
```